# Filtering on two conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and have the following table, which I would like to filter to exclude the records in which `ID` = 2 and `GRP` = X, and `ID` = 3 and `GRP`  = X, as these were entered in error.

```
ID    GRP
1     X
2     B
2     X
3     C
3     X
```

What is the correct syntax to do so? My desired end result table is:

```
ID    GRP
1     X
2     B
3     C
```

Comment: Combine two `AND`s that you've mentioned by `OR`

Comment: So, you want records that are NOT(grp = x AND (id = 2 or id = 3)), right? There's your condition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using row value constructor:

```
SELECT *
FROM  tab
WHERE (ID, GRP) NOT IN ((2,'X'),(3,'X'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE ID NOT IN (2,3) AND GRP <> 'X'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE (ID <> 2 OR ID <> 3)  AND GRP <> 'X'
```